# How to combine byte[] and ushort enum

Tags: c#

Here is my array:

```
byte[] buffer = builder.SizedByteArray();
```

Here is my enum:

```
public enum ClientOpcode : ushort
{
    CLIENT_AUTH_CONNECTION                            = 0x001,
    CLIENT_LOGIN_REQUEST                              = 0x002,
    CLIENT_NUM_MSG_TYPES                              = 0x003,
}
```

How can I prepend any `ClientOpcode` infront of `buffer` ?

I would like to extend the `buffer` with two bytes on the beginning and place the `ClientOpcode` there.

Is it possible and how ?

Comment: Get the bytes of your enum value with e.g.: `BitConverter.GetBytes` and then concatenate the two arrays?

Comment: why not use `BitConverter` and combine what you need?

Comment: `var combined = new byte[] { (byte)opcode }.Concat(buffer).ToArray();`

Comment: @JohnWu but does that guarantee that the code will be set with lenght of the first two bytes ?

Comment: @UnholySheep can you form up a complete answer? How can I place the `ClientCode` at the length of the first two bytes ?

Comment: If you want the opcode to serialize as something bigger than a single byte, you're going to have to choose [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), then add a 0 to the array, e.g. `var combined = new byte[] { (byte)opcode, 0 }.Concat(buffer).ToArray();` for LSB-first.

Comment: @JohnWu I would like to have the first two bytes in the byte array reserved for the opcode. And the opcode to be placed there. Can you form up a complete answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: @JohnWu this `var combined = new byte[] { (byte)opcode, 0 }.Concat(buffer).ToArray();` creates 4 bytes bigger array. Why ? It needs to create only 2 bytes bigger array.

Comment: I don't think that code creates a 4 bytes bigger array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution:

```
    public static Byte[] PrependClientOpcode(byte[] byteArray, ClientOpcode code)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[byteArray.Length + 2];
        buffer[0] = (byte)((ushort)code / 0x0100);
        buffer[1] = (byte)code;
        Array.Copy(byteArray, 0, buffer, 2, byteArray.Length);
        return buffer;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var buffer = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x11 };
var result2 = PrependClientOpcode(buffer, ClientOpcode.CLIENT_AUTH_CONNECTION);
```

If you want to prepend the code to EXISTING ByteBuffer then do:

```
    FlatBufferBuilder fbb = new FlatBufferBuilder(2);
    fbb.PutByte(0xff);
    fbb.PutByte(0x55);//add some random data for testing purposes
    
    //solution
    var code = ClientOpcode.CLIENT_AUTH_CONNECTION;
    fbb.AddByte((byte)((ushort)code / 0x0100));
    fbb.AddByte((byte)code);
```

Comment: how do we guarantee that we reserve the first two bytes for the `ClientOpcode` ?

Comment: also this looks like it is not working correctly. If I send the buffer like that the `ClientOpcode` is not present there.

Comment: sir can you please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784886/c-sharp-unable-to-send-tcp-header-of-type-ushort-and-read-it-correctly

Comment: @Venelin I have edited my answer. Now that should suit your needs. The first two bytes will be for the code because of the explicit assignment.

Comment: In what way it doesn't work? The result2 doesn't contain the prefix data? Or the data at all?

Comment: @Venelin do you want to prepend that code to the EXISTING buffer or to its COPY that you get by SizedByteArray?

Comment: I would like to prepend to the existing.

Comment: @Venelin I have edited my solution to prepend it to EXISTING buffer (The last part)

Comment: again it is not working. Let me show you what I have done: https://pastebin.com/9HP2JmfG and than into the console i get the output `BUffer size:56` and `BUffer size2:56`. I believe it is not extending infront with 2 bytes. Can you please check ?

Comment: @Venelin Actually it does work. Please note that: 1. FlatBufferBuilder has a defined size in bytes- you define it as a parameter to the constructor. 2. When you define FlatBufferBuilder of size of 10 and you push only 4 characters to it it means that first 4 bytes are taken. The rest is there waiting for more data BUT STILL the byte array of buffer is 10. So even if we push additional 2 bytes of OpCode in front the total size of the buffer is still 10. ONLY when you reach the max of the buffer (10 bytes in my example) the buffer will be extended to size of 12 to push your  OpCode in the front

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224467/discussion-between-pk-and-venelin).

Comment: Can you join in the chat please ?

Answer (score 0):

As `sizeof(ushort)` is 2 bytes, how about allocating a new `byte[]` that is exactly 2 bytes larger than `buffer`, copying all elements from `buffer` into the new array while leaving the first two bytes for the opcode using [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?view=net-5.0). Then we convert the opcode to it's byte representation using [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_Int16_) and store the resulting two bytes in the front two bytes of the array:

```cs
public static byte[] PrependOpcode(byte[] buffer, ClientOpcode opcode)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[buffer.Length + 2];

    // dstOffset is 2 so that we leave the first 2 bytes for the opcode.
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, result, 2, buffer.Length);

    byte[] opcodeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort) opcode);

    result[0] = opcodeBytes[0];
    result[1] = opcodeBytes[1];

    return result;
}
```

Above method can then be called like this:

```cs
byte[] buffer = builder.SizedByteArray();

buffer = PrependOpcode(buffer, ClientOpcode.CLIENT_AUTH_CONNECTION);
```

Does this do the job?

Comment: Somehow it is not working. Let me show you how I prepend and send with C++: https://pastebin.com/jh0XwjAj and this works, but with C++. Here is the server code which reads the header: https://pastebin.com/hY4yrZnk However If I prepend the ClientOpcode as you suggested I get output on the server `UNKNOWN HEADER CODE` which means it was unable to read it. Here is how I send it with C# https://pastebin.com/axaV1BBX . Tell me if more information is needed. Do you have any idea where the problem might be ?

Comment: can you check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784886/c-sharp-unable-to-send-tcp-header-of-type-ushort-and-read-it-correctly